# ZIP Entire Directory with Password

Tags: java, zip

How can I ZIP an entire directory (including subfolders) and protect the ZIP with a password + encrypt the contents?

This is java

Comment: By using methods contained within the [java.util.zip](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javazip/index.htm) Package. The [package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) provides classes for reading and writing the standard ZIP and GZIP file formats.

Comment: @DevilsHnd `java.util.zip` doesn't support encrypted zip files.

Comment: You need to find a third-party library that supports encrypted zip files. Please don't ask here, because [questions asking us to recommend or find a software library is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). So time to start up that web search engine and do some research of your own.

Answer (score 0):

With [zip4j](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j), you can encrypt a folder like this:

```
new ZipFile("file.zip", "your_password".toCharArray()).addFolder("/path/to/your/folder");
```